# using C++ vector as a buffer

Tags: c++, vector, append

I am using vector as a buffer to store some objects to be later appended to another vector.

```
std::vector<Link*> buffer_vector;
std::vector<Link*> main_vector;
main_vector.insert(main_vector.end(),buffer_vector.begin(),buffer_vector.end());
```

The process of filling the buffer and appending occurs repeatedly. Therefore I need to clear the buffer at every iteration. My concern is if I use .erase or .clear methods to clear the buffer, the objects in the main vector will be deleted. Is this assumption correct?
If yes, is there a workaround for that?

Thank you

vahid

Comment: To format code, select it and press Ctrl-K or else the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is incorrect.

`main_vector.insert(main_vector.end(),buffer_vector.begin(),buffer_vector.end());` *copies* the elements from `buffer_vector` into `main_vector`.

These copied elements are totally separate from the original elements, and so they are not affected by modifications to the elements that they were copied from.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean clearing the `buffer_vector` will clear the contents in `main_vector`, no they are separate copies.

Comment: this is a vector of pointers. I am updating my question. please read after a few moments

Comment: the pointers get copied still - deleting the old pointers does nothing, the copied pointers point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion into a vector is done by copy.  In other words, you're pushing a copy of the element into the new vector.  A different copy will be deleted when the buffer vector is cleared.

(This assumes that you're pushing the same type into both vectors, and not something like a pointer to an element to a vector in the first vector into the second vector.)

Comment: oh yes! this is a vector of pointers. I am updating my question. please read after a few moments

Comment: Regardless of whether the elements are pointers or not, `vector::insert` will make copies of them, and so the operation is safe.

Comment: A copy of the pointer will be made then.  Just make sure you *delete* the pointer once and only once.  The vector will not *delete* for you, for as long as you only delete pointers out of your last vector, you should be fine (assuming every pointer makes its way there).  You will, however, have issues if the pointer points to a stack-allocated element and it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the elements into the vector, and they will stay there until you delete them.

Comment: Pointers or not , they are copied.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you show, you are storing pointers into objects. The pointers will be copied, and nothing will happen to the allocated memory when the original vector is `clear`ed or the elements `erase`d.

Actually nothing will happen to the pointed memory when the second vector goes out of scope!! Your program leaks memory, you need to manually manage the pointers or else choose an appropriate smart pointer that you can use inside a vector (consider `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` from C++11 or the equivalents from boost or TR1).

Comment: The program only leaks memory if those pointers are pointing to objects which never get destroyed.

Comment: @Mankarse: Fair point, but since the question explicitly asks whether *the objects in the main vector will be deleted* my assumption is that  he expects them to be deleted when the vector goes out of scope. If he is expecting it, I assume that the objects are allocated from the free store and never explicitly `delete`d

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused about how a `vector` manages its objects. When you `push_back` into a vector, you make a copy. When you `push_back` a pointer, it copies the pointer. When you call `clear()` or `erase()` it deletes the pointer but not the *object* the pointer points to.

I am assuming you `new`'ed all your `Link` objects and added them to the `vector` container. You will need to delete them yourself, the container will not destroy the pointed to object for you (even if the container itself is destroyed when it goes out of scope). If you `clear()` both your containers before calling `delete` on all your `Link` objects, you will cause a memory leak (assuming you are not keeping pointers to `Link` objects somewhere else).

Comment: when i insert the first vector to another one and then .clear() the first vector, I have a track of those objects (i will delete them later) any other sign of memory link might be there?.

Comment: @rahman: If you have pointers to all the objects separate from the pointers in the arrays, then no, there should be no memory leak when you delete them through the original pointers (that are not in the containers). Although keep in mind that as soon as you delete the object(s) through any of the pointer aliases, all pointers pointing to that object are now invalid.